# Create and restore snapshot in Xcode 13 just like Android Studio with Android Emulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I use Android Studio and Xcode to develop Android and iOS apps respectively.

When I use Android Studio, I can use an option to create a snapshot on android emulator. This way I can restore the snapshot and continue the development using the same data that stored in Sqlite database and SharedPreferences.

I use Xcode and want to replicate the behavior do the same process on the iOS simulator because I want to retain data in UserDefaults and the Sqlite database.

I see some options to do that in a very old version of Xcode, but can't find it in the Xcode 13 version.

Is it possible to create and restore a snapshot on Xcode 13 and iOS Simulator just like in Android Studio with Android Emulator ?

If is not possible, there is any other way or workaround to do something similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround since I can't find a way to use snapshot with Xcode and
iOS Simulator.

I use the following code in my app:

```
print("home directory: \(NSHomeDirectory())" )
```

This code shows where the iOS simulator folder of the app is located

With that information, I can find the database.sqlite file. I can copy and backup the file or edit the info inside direct in the database.sqlite file.

This way I can use the app and restore the database.sqlite when I want to.

After I edit some info in this file, I just need to remember to run the app again using Ctrl+R.

The same is valid with the file that contains the UserDefaults data stored by the app. This file is located inside
HomeDirectory/Library/Preferences/<app_bundle_id>.plist

You can edit and backup the file if you want, but if you modify the file, remember to run the app again with Xcode.